# ASP.net MVC SelectList filed with all roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get All roles From my dataBase into select List.
This my controler :

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles(), "ROLEID", "ROLENAME");
    return View();
}
```

My Model :

```
public List<SelectListItem> SelectedRoles { set; get; }
```

An this is my View :

```
<div class="input-group">
   <label for="Centre">Roles(s)</label>
   @Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.SelectedRoles, (ViewBag.Roles as SelectList), new { @class = "chosen-select", data_placeholder = "Agent(s)." })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.SelectedRoles)
</div>
```

But I get this error :

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'SelectedRoles'.

What's the problem ?

Comment: Is your view strongly typed? If so, what's the model type?

Comment: Yes I use `RegisterModel` From Account Model, that built in ASP.net MVC4 Internet App by default.

Comment: You haven't returned the model to the view e.g. `return View(myModel)`

Comment: This problem occurs, because the next page don't have a ViewData, try copy the same code to the next view after form submit

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm using Viewbag it's automaticly returned to view normaly.

Comment: @DanielMelo It's not form submit it simple httpGet page

Comment: I can see you have added `Roles` to ViewBag, but where have you added your model property `SelectedRoles`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke In the RegisterModel used in my View and register page

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I forgot one thing, replace ListBoxFor To ListBox, like this:

```
ViewBag.ListRoles = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles(), "Id", "Name");

@Html.ListBox("SelectedRoles", (SelectList)ViewBag.ListRoles)
```

make sure that the names are not similar with ViewBag

**EDIT**

It's not a better way but i think works. Put inside View:

```
<select>
@foreach (var item in Roles.GetAllRoles())
{
    <option value="@item">@item</option>
}
</select>
```

Comment: I got this error : `DataBinding : 'System.String' doesn't have 'Id' property.`

Comment: Ok, verify if your Roles Table in database have attribute "Id" and "Name".

Comment: the table in dataBase I got "ROLEID" and "ROLENAME" but this not working, I tried to change that I got same error

Comment: So I'm using ListBoxFor because I have to save selected Value in `myModel.SelectedRoles` so ListBox doesn't solve my problems

Comment: @Chlebta, i think you want manage user of the web sites, you can do this with <select>. If you want, tell me about your situation for i can help

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.SelectedRoles, (ViewBag.Roles as SelectList), new { @class = "chosen-select", data_placeholder = "Agent(s)." })
```

change above line to

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.ROLEID, (ViewBag.Roles as SelectList), new { @class = "chosen-select", data_placeholder = "Agent(s)." })
```

Comment: `m.ROLEID` it's not a property in my model

Comment: then use the property of your model. 
you can get an idea from here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/P0CoT1

Comment: Thank you my friend for you essay but I have already resolved the problem see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have Sloved the problem like this : 

 in Controller :

```
 ViewBag.AllRoles = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles(), "roleName");
```

and in my View :

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.SelectedRoles, (ViewBag.AllRoles as SelectList), new { @class = "chosen-select", data_placeholder = "Agent(s)." })
```

This link was very helpfull [here](http://www.rtur.net/blog/post/2009/06/03/Quick-and-dirty-role-management-in-ASPNET-MVC)