# MVC Membership Get selectList of roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-membership

I just switched my entire application over to using MVC membership using LDAP that my supervisor wrote.  Logging in and authenticating works.  However, now I need to change the selectLists in my application to pull roles in the membership tables and also pull users in the Technician role.  My first crack at the pulling all roles includes this attempt:

in my controller:

```
ViewBag.TypeId = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles(), "Id", "Name");
```

and then the code in my razor view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.DropDownList("TypeId", null, "Select Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I found this but I cannot see how to save the ID in the list is captured or how to convert it to a dropdownlist as opposed to a ListBox:

[ASP.net MVC SelectList filed with all roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161384/asp-net-mvc-selectlist-filed-with-all-roles)

Here is the error I receive on the dropdownlist in my view:

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'RoleId'.

and here is the table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewBag.TypeId = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles(), "RoleId", "RoleName");
```

You can get `SelectList` of roles like following.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TypeId, (SelectList)ViewBag.TypeId, "Select Type", new  { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thank you for the Help Azim.  Unfortunately, I am getting this error with that code: "An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'RoleId'."  I am pretty sure this has something to do particularly with MVC membership.

Comment: There is no `RoleId` in your seleclist. See the updated answer.

Comment: Sorry I received that error also when I originally had Id in my selectList so I tried by replacing Id RoleId (since that is the name of the field in the asp membership table).  So I tried it again and that is what I received.

Comment: Ok, verify if your Roles Table in database have attribute "Id" and "Name"

Comment: no, they have a RoleId and RoleName - that is why I changed it.  The first time I tried it with Id and Name because that is the code I found on the web for working with Membership (and thought it may be the standard way of working with MVC membership).

Comment: Ok. Then if get all roles correctly my solution should work.

Comment: Azim, thank you for all your assistance but it is not working. I will update the original post with the error that I receive.